# Angular - Ionic: Make select dropdown look like a text link

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, ionic-framework, dropdown

So I'd like to make the select tag dropdown look like a normal text link, but when clicked have it still activate ionics select (mobile dropdown) feature.(http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select)

This plunkr down below shows the look of the dropdown box I don't want. Can anyone help me turn the dropdown box into a text link please!

```
  <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/A9ycYBKC1GUDhpCiskr5?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to your plunker works:

```
<style>
    select{
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        background: none;
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to remove the select entirely and mock it using an unordered list. [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/b8I20SraOCBAd1OgaJlg?p=preview).

```
  <a href="" ng-init="show = true" ng-click="show = !show">Link</a>
  <ul ng-if="show">
  <li ng-repeat="color in colors">
    <a href="" ng-click="setColor(color)">{{color.name}}</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! I tried this but unfortunately getting rid of the select element eliminates ionic's mobile select functionality.